# Putting a statement in once before the loop

Tags: java, loops, formatting

My working code:

public class SimpleStackDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    SimpleStack sT1 = new SimpleStack(10); 
    char ch; 

    System.out.println("Outputs:" + "\rDemonstrate SimpleStack" + "\n");
    System.out.println("Push 10 items onto a 10-element stack." + "\rPushing: ");

    for(ch = 'A'; ch < 'K'; ch++) {
        sT1.push(ch);
        System.out.print(ch);
```

Gives me this output:

```
Outputs:
Demonstrate SimpleStack

Push 10 items onto a 10-element stack.
Pushing: 
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

But I want it to give me this output:

```
Outputs:
Demonstrate SimpleStack

Push 10 items onto a 10-element stack.
Pushing: ABCDEFGHIJ
```

I can't figure out how to bring the A-J up one in front of Pushing: . I have tried `\b` , I have tried putting it within the loop and before the loop, and I will either get `Pushing: A` `Pushing: B` etc or some other iteration where pushing gets thrown in multiple times.

Is this a simple thing I am not seeing which doesn't require me to do a whole new block of coding?

Comment: suppose you use `System.out.print("Pushing: ");` in a separate line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `System.out.print()` for the label:

```
System.out.println("Push 10 items onto a 10-element stack.");
System.out.print("Pushing: ");

for (ch = 'A'; ch < 'K'; ch++) {
    sT1.push(ch);
    System.out.print(ch);
}
```

Note that I removed the `\r` you were using as newline and instead used `System.out.println()`.  This will let Java use the line separator which is appropriate for your system.

Comment: OH. MY. GOD.  Seriously!  I am a dang pleeb.  Of course I didn't think of that... wow.